# Using Blazor as a general templating tool

Tags: c#, templates, blazor

I am building out a C# application where a user can pass an object with custom data and then i use string formatting to insert the custom data into a set format. Once formatted the string is sent outbound via TCP. Is it possible to leverage Blazor templates in this use case for efficiency? I am aware this is possible with some other languages using 3rd party templating engines but didnt know if this was possible with c#.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, in my mind i guess Blazor and Razor were the same thing.